# SQL import using Java

Tags: java, mysql, export

I have tried to export and import the data base in my java project.But the execute command doesnt work. Following is the code I've done.

```
    public boolean exportDatabase(String fromServer, String FileName, String FilePath, int ExportOpions)
    {

        try {
            Class.forName(Driver).newInstance();
        }
        catch (final InstantiationException e) {
            NLogger.writeDebugLog(e);
        }
        catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
            NLogger.writeDebugLog(e);
        }
        catch (final java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        NLogger.writeDebugLog(e);
    }
    try {

        String dbName ="DBsample";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass ="root";


        String executeCmd ="CD "+FilePath+" mysqldump -u "+dbUser+ "-p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+ ">" +FileName;

        Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
        if(processComplete == 0){
        System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
        } 
        else {
        System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
        }
    return true;
    }
    catch (final Exception ex) {
        NLogger.writeErrorLog("Database Connection Failed ", ex.toString());
        NLogger.writeDebugLog(ex);
        return false;
    }

}
```

This shows an error as

"Cannot run program "CD": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: mysqldump is for exporting, am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running command then, you need to prepend `"cmd"` to your_command_to_be_run.

Make it as :

```
String executeCmd ="cmd CD "+FilePath+" mysqldump -u "+dbUser+ "-p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+ ">" +FileName;
```

Also I do not know command to export, but it seems your command is wrong. You should directly specify directory. You are using `cd` in your command. Consider following example :

```
C:\mydir1\mydir2\some.exe   // this is correct
cmd cd C:\mydir1\mydir2 some.exe   // this is wrong
```

Comment: @Gapchoos this address? can you be more clear what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

first set **System Variable** like

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;`

then

`String executeCmd = mysqldump -u "+dbUser+ "-p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+ ">" +FileName;`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DbConnectionAdress, DbName, DbSifre);
    statement = conn.createStatement();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

String DbConnectionAdress = " "

DbName = ""

DbSifre = ""
```

Comment: hakanpekcan: never ever have an 'catch-all' exception handler without any exception handling. Thats very bad style and can (and will) cause great confusion! I will edit in a fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

> String executeCmd ="FilePath+" mysqldump -u "+dbUser+ "-p"+dbPass+"
>   "+dbName+ ">" +FileName;